# Search in Ng-Repeat without hiding anything

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

The title may be a bit confusing. Please take a look at the code below,

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="test"><br/>
<div ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test"> {{ x }}</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

with these codes i can search for a name from scope.names. But the problem is, i don't want to hide other results while searching for a particular name. Which means, when i search "Gustav", it should be on top of the list without hiding other names. It would be more great if names were sorted by the matching of  supplied keyword.  Please help in this.

Comment: Can you show us some kind of visual for what you want to do here?  My knee jerk reaction is that this should be handled in the controller or maybe using a directive.

Comment: Imagine that the list looks like " cat, dog, parrot" , when i search for "dog", the list should look like "dog,cat,parrot" . :D

Comment: What about second repeat below where filter would be `filter:!test`? Just an idea, not a serious solution. I think there are many better ways but I just contrive now

Comment: Oh, wait. You have an `orderBy` filter. Try it! :)

Comment: can you please show me an exxample?

Comment: Make your own custom filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy is one of the options for the desired effect:

```
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="test"><br/>
<div ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:customOrdering"> {{ x }}</div>
{{ log }}

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "";
$scope.names = [
    'Jani',
    'Carl',
    'Margareth',
    'Hege',
    'Joe',
    'Gustav',
    'Birgit',
    'Mary',
    'Kai'
];
$scope.customOrdering = function(a) {
    return a.indexOf($scope.test) == -1;
    //return a.toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.test.toUpperCase()) == -1;   
    // use that for case insensitive search
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing happened when i searched for "Joe"

Comment: **Thank you** so much......  It doesn't  work just because i skipped  //return a.toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.test.toUpperCase()) == -1;   
    // use that for case insensitive search .

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work when using on a scope like {name:"banks",id:5"},.. But working fine on scope.names = ['jani','anotherone'];

Comment: Let me try this. Thankyou once again.